# handling files having same name (series of files)

Tags: c++

I am bit new to file handling. So bit confusing with the following thing as I cannot figure out how it would be.

I have two series of text files (I think, file format will not be a problem). For example I could say `my_1.txt, my_2.txt, ..., my_50.txt` and also `your_1.txt, your_2.txt....your_60.txt`

All these files are in my working folder where my C++ project creates executables.

Now, I want to read these two data series and want to make two separate vectors.

Can anyone show how to read the files by avoiding the erroneous order and names as i have many files (same format) with different names (without getting support from some libraries)?

actually, i am looking some starting point and got this http://forum.codecall.net/topic/60157-read-all-files-in-a-folder/
would it be a good option to continue?

Comment: @H2CO3: thanks... can you give some example please

Comment: @g-makulik: still researching and trying to follow http://forum.codecall.net/topic/60157-read-all-files-in-a-folder/

Comment: @gnp As long this isn't homework, I wouldn't recommend a non portable approach.

Comment: @g-makulik: (didn't get what you said) this is not a homework and struggling and learning by my self.. please give me some positive response. thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32211/discussion-between-g-makulik-and-gnp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boost , you could read all the directory contents .

```
typedef vector<path> vec;             // store paths,
vec v;                                // so we can sort them later
copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration

Ok for without library 
Use dirent its availaible on linux 
dirent.h is a POSIX header. On Windows you use the Find*File*() functions in the Win32 API.

Comment: many thanks... but me I am looking for without any libraries.